# Inflating My Bike Tyres

Tags: pump

and just bought a bike and needs to inflate the tyres. I bought a muddyfox trade pump - see attached pics- but still can't fix the air pump head into my wheel. I guess it could be the wrong size or fit, can any one help what to do and how to do this? 
Thanks

[image]

Comment: 'muddyfox trade pump' do you mean 'muddyfox track pump '? On their website it says Presta and Schrader. So look at the chuck, there is an invertible bit, your picture shows the Presta position.

Answer (score 10):

That pump is set up for another sort of valve (Presta, you have Schrader). You can probably switch it by unscrewing the end, removing the rubber part and putting it back in the other way round. You might need to turn round a plastic or metal part as well.

Comment: Yes - check the manual/packaging for your pump if you still have it.